Live Autocomplete Search code has stopped working
I found and used this code on my site when I first built it years ago and it's never let me down, until now.. Unfortunately I can't find the original source.
Up until recently, if I began typing in a word a box underneath would automatically offer related posts or posts with matching tags which you could click on.
<form rrole="search" method="get" class="et_pb_searchform" action="https://brightonbeerblog.com/" target="_self"> 
  
    <div>
      
            <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
            <input type="text" value="" name="s" class="et_pb_s" data-swplive="true">
  
          <label class="mag-glass"</label>  
                <img src="*removed code as 'You need at least 10 reputation to post images.'*" alt="" />
                
        </div>
</form>


Clearly somethings changed in the way this function works in wordpress but I don't have the skills to see what. I'd love to understand what changed recently and if this code can still be used if adapted?
Many thanks
